# what delf/dalf level is French version Matilda?

Tags: niveau-de-langue

Matilda is a book by Roald Dahl, it's also translated to [French](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/2070601587?pf_rd_r=DM3XENSCHZT12V3HCRAR&pf_rd_p=70373c30-7461-4a24-bb1f-f3fde4f2df3a).

May I ask, which delf/dalf level is this French version Matilda equivalent to? of course, I'm referring to reading, not about listening, speaking, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems somewhat subjective because I was not able to find a formal classification of the book online. I'm assuming you're referring to Henri Robillot's translation. The book is often suggested to French students in 4th/5th  grade (American System) which would be CM1/CM2 in France (based on past experience and a quick internet search). This would mean it's a [DELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d%27%C3%A9tudes_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) Prim level, more towards A2.